# Why can't other users access my SAMBA share without force user = me?

Tags: samba, settings, shared-folders

I have a Samba related problem.

I have a successful samba server set up on my home server. Unfortunately only my account can access the shares when force user is not set to my account (server). I cannot understand why the other user cannot access my share "Vector_Public" when I haven't set "force user = server". Do you have any ideas to what might cause this? I'm a Samba noob so please if I've misunderstood any of the settings:

```
[Vector_Public]
   comment = Vector public share
   read only = no
   path = /media/Storage/Public
   guest ok = no
   force user = server
   force group = storage_public
   create mask = 0770
   directory mask = 0770
   security mask = 0770
   force create mode = 0770
   force directory mode = 0770
   valid users = server storage_share
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   vfs objects = recycle
   recycle:repository = .deleted/%U
   recycle:keeptree = yes
   recycle:touch = yes
   recycle:versions = yes
   recycle:maxsize = 0

[Vector_Private]
   comment = Vector private share (Niklas)
   read only = no
   path = /media/Storage/Private
   guest ok = no
   force user = server
   force group = server
   create mask = 0770
   directory mask = 0770
   security mask = 0770
   force create mode = 0770
   force directory mode = 0770
   valid users = server
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   vfs objects = recycle
   recycle:repository = .deleted/%U
   recycle:keeptree = yes
   recycle:touch = yes
   recycle:versions = yes
   recycle:maxsize = 0
```

The permissions on the two directories are:

```
drwx------ 6 server server 4096 2011-10-05 20:40 Private
drwxrwx--- 5 server storage_public 4096 2011-10-05 20:28 Public
```

It's the directory Public that I have this problem on.

Apparently none of the settings under the share Vector_Public changes this behaviour so it must be because of some other setting, these are all the other settings in my config:

```
   workgroup = ROSENQVIST
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
#   wins support = no
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
   dns proxy = no
;   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
#   syslog only = no
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = user
# 'encrypt passwords' in the smb.conf(5) manpage before enabling.
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
;   domain logons = yes
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   printing = bsd
;   printcap name = /etc/printcap
;   printing = cups
;   printcap name = cups
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash
;   winbind enum groups = yes
;   winbind enum users = yes
;   usershare max shares = 100
   usershare allow guests = no
```

Any ideas what I should do? (please also check the new comments)

Additionally, how do I know if my network have WINS server support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of an issue with flow of permissions. Everything worked when I changed the parent directory's (to the directories that were shared) permissions to allow reading for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Your public folder only provides access to users who are either "server" or are in the group "storage_public". If you don't use "force user" and allow anonymous access then the share is probably accessed with the user nobody, which is not in "storage_public".

You probably want to change the permissions of your Public folder to "drwxrwxr-x", which would make it possible for Samba users to read from but not write to the Public folder.

To do this, use "chmod o+rX Public"

With regard to WINS:

It's not your network that has WINS support, but individual servers that can provide it. You can enable wins support in a particular server by setting "wins support = yes".

Comment: Thanks I will try this later when I get the time. What benefits does wins offer? Should I enable it?

Comment: But it isn't an anonymous user. It's the user called storage_share and he is both in valid users and the group storage_public. Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: The alternative to WINS is NetBIOS browsing, which uses broadcasting. In a small network that already works I wouldn't bother setting up WINS.

Comment: You have "bad user = map to guest" set, which means that all access by invalid users will automatically be changed into access by a guest. That makes things harder to debug and is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, ok, I will change that and see if it works better. Thanks Jelmer!